# Select TOP Elements in a Group with EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have following entities, basically `User` and `Message` have M2M relationship via `MsgGroup`. Also first message in a thread (or group) has `ThreadId=MessageId`, where others share the same `ThreadId`

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.InverseProperty("Received")]
    public virtual System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<MsgGroup> ReceivedGroups { get; set; }
}

public class Message
{
    public int MessageId { get; set; }
    public int ThreadId { get; set; }
    public virtual System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<MsgGroup> MsgGroups { get; set; }
}

public class MsgGroup
{
    public int MsgGroupId { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User Received { get; set; }

    public int MessageId { get; set; }
    public virtual Message Message { get; set; }
}
```

I want to get lates messages in groups for a given user. Particularly the following SQL query:

```
select * from messages where MessageId IN (
    SELECT MaxId FROM (
        select ThreadId , MAX(MessageId) as MaxId from messages where ThreadId in (
            select distinct MessageId from msggroups where UserId = 1
        ) 
        GROUP BY ThreadId
    ) AS t1
)
```

I have tried:

```
var query = from grp in db.MsgGroups.Where(g => g.UserId == userId)
select new
{
    f = (from msg in db.Messages where (msg.ThreadId == grp.MessageId) select msg).OrderByDescending(m => m.Date).Take(1)
};
```

however it creates a very complex query where there are subqueries for each field of message.

Is there a solution? Also can I ask the same question in method based format and query expression format (since I can't figure out in query expression format at all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested below query exactly did what I requested, only difference is it used `JOIN`s instead of `IN`s in my question:

```
var query = 
from mm in
(
    from grp in db.MsgGroups.Where(g => g.UserId == userId)
    from msg in db.Messages
    where msg.ThreadId == grp.MessageId
    group msg by msg.ThreadId into thr
    select new { t = thr.Key, m = thr.Max(t => t.MessageId) }
)
join omsg in db.Messages
on mm.m equals omsg.MessageId
select new { t = mm.t, m = omsg.Text } ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be looking to do a join, maybe something like this, this will get you the most recent messages for a particular user, ordered by thread ID, you can replace 100 in the **Take** section with how many messages you want:

```
var query = (from grp in db.MsgGroups
    .Join(
        db.Messages,
        g => g.MessageId,
        m => m.ThreadId,
        (g, m) => new { grp = g, mgs = m })
        .Where(x => x.grp.UserId == userId)
    select new
    {
        Message = grp.mgs
    })
    .Take(100)
    .OrderByDescending(t => t.Message.ThreadId);
```

This will give you a collection of anonymous objects, each one having a single property called Message, which is the Message object you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use the navigation properties and let EF take care of the SQL joins:

```
var query = from rg in db.MsgGroups
            where rg.UserId == userId
            group rg by rg.ThreadId into thread
            select new { 
                         Thread = thread.Key, 
                         LastMessage = thread.Select(t => t.Message)
                                             .OrderByDescending(m => m.Date)
                                             .FirstOrDefault()
                       };
```

This gives you the last message for each thread the user has messages in.